# Trying to apply a filter to a nested array full of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, foreach, javascript-objects

I have a resources array which is full of objects. Each object has categories array full of objects. I am trying to apply a filter to only return resources that have category objects of a specific name. I am having some trouble with the nesting of my data object.

Here is the data I am working with:

```
const resources = [
  {
    title: 'Learn JS',
    categories: [
      {
        name: 'javascript'
      },
      {
        name: 'css'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Learn CSS',
    categories: [
      {
        name: 'css'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Learn other stuff',
    categories: [
      {
        name: 'jQuery'
      },
      {
        name: 'javascript'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Learn node',
    categories: [
      {
        name: 'node'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'Learn React',
    categories: [
      {
        name: 'react'
      }
    ]
  },

];
```

Here are my two attempts. Both return empty arrays. Am I wrong to be trying to use `maps` and `filters`. Is a `for loop` necessary?

```
//GOAL: Return only the resources that have a category with name 'javascript'
const attemptOne = resources.filter((item) => {
  return item.categories.forEach((thing, index) => {
    return thing[index] === 'javascript'
  });
}).map((item) => {
  return item;
})

const attemptTwo = resources.filter((item) => {
  item.categories.filter((ci) => {
    return ci.name === 'javascript'
  }).map((nextItem) => {
    return nextItem;
  });
})
```

I have been stumbling around with this for a while, and I am not sure if I am just over complicating it our what. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Returning a value from `forEach` won't accomplish anything. Perhaps you are looking for `Array#some`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `filter` on `resources`. Inside the filter, since you already know that an object has categories, you can just use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if the category name you are looking for is included

```js
const resources = [{
  title: 'Learn JS',
  categories: [{
    name: 'javascript'
  }, {
    name: 'css'
  }]
}, {
  title: 'Learn CSS',
  categories: [{
    name: 'css'
  }]
}, {
  title: 'Learn other stuff',
  categories: [{
    name: 'jQuery'
  }, {
    name: 'javascript'
  }]
}, {
  title: 'Learn node',
  categories: [{
    name: 'node'
  }]
}, {
  title: 'Learn React',
  categories: [{
    name: 'react'
  }]
}];

function filterViaCategory(arr, category) {
  return arr.filter(obj => obj.categories.some(cat => cat.name === category));
}

console.log(filterViaCategory(resources, 'javascript'));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `filter` and `some` array methods:

```
function getResourcesByCategoryName(Resources, CategoryName){

      return Resources.filter(function(resource){
               return resource
                      .categories
                      .some(function(category){ return category.name == CategoryName; });
             });
}
```