# JS (ES6): Filter array based on nested array attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6

I have an array, which looks like this:

```
const persons = [
  {
    name: "Joe",
    animals: [
      {species: "dog", name: "Bolt"},
      {species: "cat", name: "Billy"},
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Bob",
    animals: [
      {species: "dog", name: "Snoopy"}
    ]
  }
];
```

Now I want to filter based on the species.
For example: every person which has a cat, should be returned:

```
const result = [
  {
    name: "Joe",
    animals: [
      {species: "dog", name: "Bolt"},
      {species: "cat", name: "Billy"},
    ]
  }
];
```

I have tried with the the `filter()` method like this:

```
const result = persons.filter(p => p.animals.filter(s => s.species === 'cat'))
```

But this doesn't return the desired result (it returns both persons).

How can I filter the array bases on an attribute of a nested array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to apply a filter to a nested array full of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517373/trying-to-apply-a-filter-to-a-nested-array-full-of-objects)

Comment: change your second `filter` to `some`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your inner filter still returns a "truthy" value (empty array) for the dog person. Add `.length` so that no results becomes `0` ("falsey")

`const result = persons.filter(p => p.animals.filter(s => s.species === 'cat').length)`

**Edit:** Per comments and several other answers, since the goal is to get a truthy value from the inner loop, `.some` would get the job done even better because it directly returns true if any items match.

`const result = persons.filter(p => p.animals.some(s => s.species === 'cat'))`

Answer (score 4):

You might want to use some'

```
 persons.filter(p => p.animals.some(s => s.species === 'cat'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const persons = [
  {
    name: "Joe",
    animals: [
      {species: "dog", name: "Bolt"},
      {species: "cat", name: "Billy"},
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Bob",
    animals: [
      {species: "dog", name: "Snoopy"}
    ]
  }
];

Filter = function(arr, a){
  return arr.filter(t=>t.animals.filter(y=>y.species==a).length>0);
}

console.log(Filter(persons, 'cat'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` with `some()` method to check if some of the objects in animals array has `species == cat`.

```js
const persons = [{"name":"Joe","animals":[{"species":"dog","name":"Bolt"},{"species":"cat","name":"Billy"}]},{"name":"Bob","animals":[{"species":"dog","name":"Snoopy"}]}]

const result = persons.filter(({animals}) => {
  return animals.some(({species}) => species == 'cat')
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
persons.filter((person) => {
    return person.animals.filter((animal) => {
        return animal.species === 'cat';
    }).length > 0;
});
```

Add the check on length, as filter returns an array, not a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You havent checked against the length of the second filter.

Filer only includes results that return a `true` value. So we need to provide the second filter with a way of returning true if it finds something. We can do that by saying, if the returned array is > 0

```js
const persons = [
  {
    name: "Joe",
    animals: [
      {species: "dog", name: "Bolt"},
      {species: "cat", name: "Billy"},
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Bob",
    animals: [
      {species: "dog", name: "Snoopy"}
    ]
  }
];

const filtered = persons.filter(p => p.animals.filter(a => a.species === "cat").length > 0)

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
const result = persons.filter(person => {
   let innerResult = person.animals.filter(animal => {
      return animal.species === 'cat';
   });

  return innerResult.length > 0;
});
```